# Perforce - unshelve files into another directory

Tags: perforce, unshelve

I have two directories into the same workspace, I shelved some files into a changelist in the first directory and now I want to unshelve them into the second.. I tried this command:

```
p4 -c my_workspace unshelve -s 17654070 -n -b //my_workspace/directory2
Branch '//my_workspace/directory2'
 unknown - use 'branch' command to create it.
```

How can I have this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create a branch spec to tell the server the relationship between the two directories.

1. run `p4 branch some_branch_name`
2. In the view field put:

   `//depot/directory1/... //depot/directory2/...`
3. Save the form and run `p4 -c my_workspace unshelve -s 17654070 -n -b some_branch_name`